# How to use two COUNT in One Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, count

I try to use multiple count in one query. Presently I am using the query below that works perfectly for one count.

```
SELECT  SERVICE, STANDARD=COUNT(SERVICE) 
FROM    INC_  
WHERE CLIENTNUM='WAYFAIRATL'
  AND DROPTIME IS NULL
  AND CANCELLED=0
  AND SERVICE LIKE 'WCMV%'
  AND CONVERT (VARCHAR(5),READYTIME, 114) = '01:00'
GROUP BY SERVICE
```

I would like to add another field to the select that counts the number of orders for each service where `INC_.SCHEDATTEMPT is null`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT  
    SERVICE, 
    COUNT(SERVICE) AS STANDARD,
    SUM(CASE WHEN INC_.SCHEDATTEMPT is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SCHEDATTEMPTISNULL
FROM    
    INC_  
WHERE 
    CLIENTNUM='WAYFAIRATL' 
    AND DROPTIME IS NULL AND CANCELLED=0 
    AND SERVICE LIKE 'WCMV%' 
    AND CONVERT (VARCHAR(5),READYTIME, 114) = '01:00'
GROUP BY 
    SERVICE
```

Comment: @A.Goutam : Np. Glad to help